# Javascript onClick not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addeventlistener

I have one (for me) strange problem.
I have pop under that open one url. i need to make when user click on some flashplayer (who is in div)
I put javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("player").click(myfunc());
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click', myfunc(), false);
</script>
```

But there is problem.. this not work on click (when user click on #player), this work when user load page ( onload ) and i dont need that, i need on click to start function...
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you appear to be missing the `#` character in your jQuery selector (I'm assuming it's meant to be an ID selector because you also gave an example using `getElementById`), so it's currently looking an element called `player`, rather than an element with ID "player".

Secondly, you don't want to execute the `myfunc` function when you pass it to the `click` function. Instead, you want to pass a reference to the function (note the lack of parentheses):

```
$("#player").click(myfunc);
```

The same is true for your second example, but you are right in that when using `getElementById` you pass in the string without the `#` character:

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click', myfunc, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send [function references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#player").click(myfunc);
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click', myfunc, false);
</script>
```

When you `$("#player").click(myfunc());`, you are actually executing `myfunc`. @Paul pointed out that you were also missing the [**jQuery id**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) identifier for you selector.

Comment: Also if those two scripts are supposed to be equivalent, then you probably want to select by id in the first one like `$('#player')`. Otherwise you are selecting a tag called `<player>` which isn't likely to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing wrong is that you do not pass the function as a reference to the jQuery click method but execute it.

Replace `$("player").click(myfunc());` with `$("player").click(myfunc);` and everything should work as expected. The same applies to your second example.